# Control ExecutorService to execute N tasks per second maximum

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

How to control/limit the tasks that are submitted to a [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)? I have `SMSTask` that sends SMS messages and I need to control the executor so that it can only send at maximum N messages/second.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you are creating one SMS message per task you can use a ScheduleExecutorService.

```
final Queue<Task> tasks = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Task>();
int ratePerSecond = 10;
final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Task task = tasks.poll();
        if (task == null) return;
        es.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                process(task);
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 1000/ratePerSecond, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Add tasks to the queue and they will be processed at a rate of 10 per second.

Comment: You could find the queue size grows too much so you might want to monitor it.

Comment: Well, we are sending 1000-2000 SMS messages per hour and it is OK since polled tasks will be garbage-collected after they finish. Right?

Comment: They can be garbage collected after used. You can have periods of more than 600 per minute, provided you also have longer periods of less activity.

Comment: BTW, does the scheduled executor use the same `Runnable` object every time? i.e. if `run()` takes more than 100 ms to execute, does the executor wait for the previous task to finish before executing the next task (since you are using newSingleThread)?

Comment: It runs the same Runnable object each time as it cannot create a new one. It waits 100 ms from the end of the task so it will slow down if sending is slow.

Comment: Oh, that's not what I need :(

Comment: Personally I would prefer the system to slow down if there is a problem sending the messages as it prevent overloading the downstream server. What sort of delay do you typically see?  Is there a reason you would want to send more messages downstream than it can keep up with?

Comment: The service provider limits us with only about 5 messages per second (extra messages won't be received by them), and the `SMSTask` takes around 0.3 s. If I use your solution then I would send around 3 messages per second. I want to take the advantage of sending 5 messages per second. I need a multi-threaded solution to use on multi-core system which would be capable of sending messages in parallel and put a control on the rate (messages/s).

Comment: I have updated my answer.  This will start a message at a constant rate, no matter how many are being performed at the same time.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly satisfying my requirements! Thank you very much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you give full package path of class Task?

Answer (score 5):

Try [`RateLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) from Guava. You must share one instance between all tasks running in the pool:

```
final RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(N)

//and in your task:

rateLimiter.tryAcquire();
sendSms();
```

`tryAcquire();` will block for the amount of time precisely to preserve `N` frequency.

#### See also:

- [*RateLimiter - discovering Google Guava*](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/09/ratelimiter-discovering-google-guava.html)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer, but I prefer not to use external library :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: no problem, maybe it'll help someone in the future. Good luck!